# javascript: sorting list of dicts by multiple (more than 2) keys

Tags: javascript, list, sorting, dictionary

In javascript, I have been trying to sort a list of dics by more than two keys but I have had problems.

```
hits = [
  {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10},
  {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10},
  {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10}
  ]

//sorting by two keys
hits.sort(function(a,b) {
       return a.key2 != b.key2? (a.key2 < b.key2? -1 : 1) :
 a.key3 - b.key3 });
```

After sorting, hits[0] key1 is still 'c', and I want it to be 'a', which means I would have to sort by a third.

PS: as you can see key2 and key3 values are the same, and I dont sort straight from key1 because in my real list of dics there are other dics where key2 and key3 looks different from this example.

In python I would simply do:

```
hits.sort(key=itemgetter('key2', 'key3',"key1"))
```

It works for a small test, but when I try with a list with many dics, the result does not make sense.

Here is part of the data:

```
Key 2     Key3       key1
chr1           11       chr1_K892
chr1           11       chr1_K761
chr2           10       chr2
```

Here is how it looks after sorting

```
Key 2     Key3       key1
chr2           10        chr2
chr1           11        chr1_K892
chr1           11        chr1_K761
```

I think it should be:

```
Key 2     Key3       key1
chr1           11        chr1_K761
chr1           11        chr1_K892
chr2           10        chr2
```

There are other keys involved, but they are not suppose to be a problem, i think since I'm ordering by 3 keys

Solution that worked:

```
        hits.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(a.key2 < b.key2)
                return -1;
            if(a.key2 > b.key2)
                return 1;
            if(a.key3 < b.key3)
                return -1;
            if(a.key3 > b.key3)
                return 1;
            if(a.key1 < b.key1)
                return -1;
            if(a.key1 > b.key1)
                return 1;

            return 0;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code states to sort in increasing order based on the value of `key2`. If the values of `key2` of both the objects are same, it will sort based on `key3`
`key1` is not at all referenced in the code.
If you want to sort in increasing order based on `key`, you can do:

```
hits = [
    {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10},
    {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10},
    {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10}
];
hits.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.key1!=b.key1 ? (a.key1 < b.key1 ? -1 : 1) : 0;
});
```

Or, if you want to sort based on key2, key3 and then key1, you may use:

```
hits = [
    {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10},
    {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10},
    {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'c1', 'key3': 10}
];
hits.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.key2 != b.key2 ? a.key2 > b.key2 : (a.key3 != b.key3 ? a.key3 > b.key3 : (a.key1 != b.key1 ? a.key1 > b.key1 : 0));
});
```

Does this serve your purpose?

Comment: It worked for a small list of 3 dics, but when I tried with for my real case with many keys and dics, it did not work. I have added the first post with more explanation

Comment: Did you invert the `>`  to `<` ? Because running this last code snippet with the same input gives me the expected scenario that you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that does sorting on array of key-value pairs.

```js
function sortArrayOfObject(arr, key, sort_order="ascend") {
    const order = sort_order.trim().toLowerCase();
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[key] > b[key]) {
            return order == "ascend" ? 1 : -1;
        }
        else if (a[key] < b[key]) {
            return order == "ascend" ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return 0;
    })
}

const testData = [{ item: 1, name: "a"}, {item: 2, name:"b"}];

console.log(sortArrayOfObject(testData, "item", "decend"));
```